# How are method calls implemented in the runtime?

Tags: objective-c, runtime, swift

Swift code can interact with Obj-C code, so, Swift can call the `objc_msg_send` function,
and use the objective-c runtime. But from [WWDC 2014 video](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2014/) Advanced Swift it is clear
that swift does not use the obj-c runtime in pure swift classes.
The Swift runtime is smaller than the obj-c runtime. And Swift binaries can be run even on older mac os x versions.

**How are method calls implemented in the runtime? Does swift use selectors?**

Comment: Uh, how is this too broad? It seems awfully specific and narrow to me.

Comment: @RobertHarvey why do you think that it is too broad? How do you determine that?

Comment: If you think the *question* is specific enough to be meaningfully answerable in a few paragraphs that can be understood by everyone, then by all means vote to reopen.  But currently I see two questions.  One can be answered "yes" or "no," the other requires establishing extensive background context before it can be meaningfully answered.  The first paragraph of the question appears to be useless for establishing context.

Comment: I can explain the obj-c dynamic binding in few paragraphs, why swift's method call could not be explained in few paragraphs?

Comment: How can we conclusively know without the source code?

Comment: @EdgarAroutiounian f.e. reverse engineering, or something else. If I could know how, I would not ask question.

Comment: Here's to hoping an Apple employee will give us a 'hint' on StackOverflow... ;)

Comment: Are you including Swift methods that use @final in the last part of your last question?